# Matlab vector to matrix conversion

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I want to convert the following vector `A` into matrix `B`, best demonstrated by this example:

```
n = 4;

A = [1 2 3 4 5 6];

B = [ 1 2 3 4;
      2 3 4 5;
      3 4 5 6; ]
```

I am currently using a loop to achieve this and wondered if it was possible to vectorize it?

Thanks L.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
A(bsxfun(@plus,[0:numel(A)-n]',1:n))
```

You can also use [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) -

```
hankel(A(1:n),A(n:end)).'
```

Sample run -

```
>> A = [3,4,6,0,1,2]
A =
     3     4     6     0     1     2
>> n
n =
     4
>> A(bsxfun(@plus,[0:numel(A)-n]',1:n))
ans =
     3     4     6     0
     4     6     0     1
     6     0     1     2
>> hankel(A(1:n),A(n:end)).'
ans =
     3     4     6     0
     4     6     0     1
     6     0     1     2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Signal Processing Toolbox you can also use [`convmtx`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html):

```
n = 4;
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6];

m = numel(A)-n;
B = flipud(convmtx(A,m+1));
B = B(:,m+1:end-m);
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting that [convmtx](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html) require the Signal Processing Toolbox

Comment: @kkuilla Good idea. I hadn't noticed